# Why 2D array for-loop checking cannot access some values?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

```
private static String[][] menuList = {{"Soda","10"},{"Coke","20"},{"Water","5"}};

public Drinks(String menu, String size) {
    setMenu(menu);
    setSize(size);
}

public void setMenu(String menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
    for (int i = 0; i < menuList.length; i++) {
        if (this.menu.equalsIgnoreCase(menuList[i][0])){
            price = Double.valueOf(menuList[i][1]);
        }else{price = 0.0;}
    }
}
```

Then I create object for testing
I can't get price of the first two rows in menuList[][]
but I can still get the last one

```
    Drinks d = new Drinks("water","L");
    Drinks e = new Drinks("coke","L");
    Drinks f = new Drinks("soda","L");
    System.out.println(d);
    System.out.println(e);
    System.out.println(f);
```

the output is

```
Drink[menu = water , size = L , price = 5.00]
Drink[menu = coke , size = L , price = 0.00]
Drink[menu = soda , size = L , price = 0.00]
```

I just want to know why? And how can I fix this?

Comment: is your `price` field static?

Comment: No, it's just // private double price;

Comment: You need to break out of your loop once you find a match. Otherwise it will continue looping and set `price` to `0.0` again.

Comment: Thanks, it's works. I need to review basic java again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are actually doing is, for each entry in `menuList`, you check if it's name corresponds to your parameter, and set (i.e. overwrite) the price field every time. It works the same as if you didn't loop but only checked the *last* item.

There The solution is to break out of the loop. I also changed where you initialize the variable to make sure it's initialized *at all*.

```
public void setMenu(String menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
    price = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < menuList.length; i++) {
        if (this.menu.equalsIgnoreCase(menuList[i][0])){
            price = Double.valueOf(menuList[i][1]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```